# Disable operation from documentation

Tags: symfony, swagger-ui, api-platform.com

In API-Platform I want to hide some operations, from the documentation. So I made the operation not found and set `openapi: false`

```php
#[ApiResource(
    // […]
    operations: [
        new Delete( controller: NotFoundAction::class, 
                    openapi: false,
                    read: false,
                    output: false 
                  )
    ]
)]
```

The operation is still shown in the documentation, do I need to do something more?

I use Api-Platform 3.2.5 and the cache folder has been deleted and warmed up again.

Comment: If you only want to hide it, it's the good way. I used your configuration and it's perfectly working. Could you check that there are no other Delete declaration (like #[Delete] and that your browser and Symfony cache are cleared? 

If you want to totally disable the Delete operation, you just need to remove this declaration and specify the other.

Comment: I checked all conditions you mentioned and it is still showing

Comment: What is your api-platform version? new Delete(openapi: false) works fine for me (v. 3.2.5).

Comment: What about a  `bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: i use v. 3.2.5 and the cache folder has been deleted and warmed up again

Answer (score 2):

In your example, there are some conflicting configurations which make unclear what you want to actually happen.

You want to the operation to **exist, but not to be shown on the generated docs**?

Simply do (this comes from an example that I had set up for something different, so ignore the other operation details):

```
#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new Get(
        provider: PingProvider::class,
    ),
    new Post(
        input: CreatePing::class,
        messenger: 'input',
    ),
    new Delete(
        openapi: false,
    )
])]
readonly class Ping
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $id,
        public string $message = 'pong'
    ) { }
}
```

This results in:
[image: swagger UI showing missing "DELETE" operation]

However, the `DELETE` operation still exists, although it would not be *documented*. But one could call `DELETE /pings/123`, and supposedly it would work.

---

Or maybe you want to **remove** the `DELETE` operation altogether?

Then simply **omit** the operation from the `operations` array:

```
#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new Get(
        provider: PingProvider::class,
    ),
    new Post(
        input: CreatePing::class,
        messenger: 'input',
    )
])]
readonly class Ping
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $id,
        public string $message = 'pong'
    )  {}
}
```

This results in the same docs:
[image: swagger UI showing missing "DELETE" operation]

But this time the `DELETE` operation would cease to work altogether. It's not simply undocumented, but calling `DELETE /pings/123` would result in a `405` response ("Method not allowed").

---

The other options are more confusing in this context. Particularly the `controller: NotFoundAction::class` one. One would use this if one wanted to show the operation in the docs, enable the operation, but do not allow accessing any result, so any calls result in a `404` ("resource not found"). It's altogether unclear why would you want this in this case.

The same could be said for the `read: false` and `output: false`. While this could conceivably be used in this scenario... it's not clear why would you want this, or how does it relate to the question.

---

You mention your config **does not work for you**. I'm sorry, but **this the configuration shown would result in the operation not to be shown in the resulting docs**. If that's not the case for you, it's more likely something else (not included in the question) is causing the results you say you get.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed answer. sadly nothing worked, I started over with a vanilly config, nothing helped. I found a way by injecting a normalizer https://t.ly/nLooh in between, this works but feels just not right, I'd rather prefere a correct behaviour without the normalizer hack.

Comment: The above just works. It’s extracted verbatim from a project I created from scratch, and simply works. In a few hours I’ll upload the whole thing as a GitHub project so you can try it out and verify.